# Retrieving a Record from a File and Assigning to Variables

Tags: c++, file-io, fstream

I have created a program which writes an object to a file(by converting it to char) and then retrieve the records from the file and assign it to variables.
.

Here is my Problem in detail:

I have a person class with two member variables called name and Address.
I create a person class object through my program and then write it to the file.
When i retrieve back the record i am only able to retrieve the name but i cannot retrieve the address.

Here is my code:-

My main class

```
int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    Person p1;
    p1.setName("Jim");
        p1.setAddress("USA");
    Person p2;


    File writeToFile;

       writeToFile.writeObject(p1); //write the object to the file using method


    fstream readFile("Filet.txt",ios::in); //creates an object of fstream to retrieve records

    // declared 2 variable to hold the values
    string name;               
    string address;

    //loop until its end of the file
    while(!readFile.eof())
    {
    readFile>>name>>address; //assign the record to the variables
    }

    p2.setName(name);  //initialize the object's members
    p2.setAddress(address);


    cout<<p2.getName()<<""<< p2.getAddress()<<endl; //print the values
    system("pause");

return 0;
}
```

Here is what the program outputs:

[image]

What seems to be the problem here ?

Thank you for your time

Edit:-

My Person Class Implementation

```
Person::Person(){}
void Person:: setName(string tname)
        {
            int length=tname.size();
            length=length<5 ? length : 4;
            tname.copy(name,length);
            name[length]='\0';
        }



 string Person::getName()
        {
           return this->name;
        }
void Person:: setAddress(string taddress)
 {
     int length=taddress.size();
     length=length<15 ? length:14;
     taddress.copy(address,length);
     address[length]='\0';
 }

 string Person:: getAddress()
{
    return this->address;
}
```

My writeObject method implementation

```
string File:: writeObject (Person obj)
        {


            fstream writeFile;
            writeFile.open("Filet.txt",ios::out |ios::in);

            if(!writeFile)
            {
                cout<<"No File"<<endl;
            }

           else
            {


                writeFile.write(reinterpret_cast<const char *>  
                                (&obj),sizeof(Person));

                outFile.close();
            }
            return "Done";

         }
```

Comment: Without access to the class `File` and the method `writeObject` I'll guess one of them has a bug or you are using it wrong. Did you look into the file if the contents is what you expect it to be?

Comment: `while(!readFile.eof())` is not good, but can you show the writeObject implementation and/or the file content you wrote? Showing the output file written would be very useful, too.

Comment: I have added all codings in the Edit.

@nvoigt yes the contents are written but after the address there are some characters.

Here is an example :- Jim(Name) ÌUSA(Address) ÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌ(Some unknown characters)

Comment: @LaszloPapp Well i have not tried writing like that since am new to c++ and c++file handling, but ill give it a try. Thanks for the tip.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "garbage written" in the output file might be due to this line:

```
writeFile.write(reinterpret_cast<const char *>(&obj),sizeof(Person));
```

reinterpret_cast will not add spaces for you automatically which is how logically the operator>> file reading would be working based on words separated by spaces.

I would say, reinterpret_cast should always be the last resort if there are better options. Based on your existing write functionality, I will assume that you prefer to write the file in text mode instead of binary.

I would simple use the following mechanism:

```
string out_str = obj.getName() + " " + obj.getAddress() + " ";
writeFile.write(out_str.c_str(), out_str.size());
```

I would personally write them line-by-line as opposed to word-by-word. Also, you will have issues if the names and addresses appear to be more than just one word, so be aware of that.

Comment: When i try the mechanism which you have given. I get a compilation error saying "Too Few Arguments in Function Call"

Comment: @Shehan.W: you forgot the out_str.size() parameter. Reinterpret cast will not add spaces for you automatically btw which is how the operator>> works.